# Magento: I can't translate [sales_email_order_items]

Tags: email, magento, translate

My problem:

In magento admin I made my own email templates (order_new.html, order_new_guest.html), and translate them. Everything works, when i buy sthing, i get a translated email, but I can't translate the names of the datas in sales_email_order_items block /'Subtotal (Excl.Tax)', 'Subtotal (Incl.Tax)', etc/ - everything else is translated in the block!

Mage_Sales.csv, Mage_Weee.csv, Mage_Tax.csv exists in locale/[country_language] directory, and translated

Does anybody know where these words come from?

Thank you the answers

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. What are those templates? what do the csv files has to do with it? Consider revising it.

Answer (score 2):

check templates at template/email/order/* Look at used helper names to find out what csv files should be changed

Answer (score 0):

The file that requires editing is:

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml
```

The translation wrapper is missing from around the attribute label output.
Change line 35:

```
<dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label']; ?></em></strong></dt>
```

to:

```
<dt><strong><em><?php echo $this->__($option['label']); ?></em></strong></dt>
```

It may also be one of the other tpl files located in the following directory, all have the same issue:

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\*\*.phtml
```

Comment: Also make sure you copy the files to your custom theme directory! Dont just edit the base files...